# Why import seaborn as sns?

Tags: python, seaborn

Why do you always import seaborn as `sns` and not with the letters of the name as `sbn`?

Is `sns` an acronym for something?

Or is it some kind of joke?

As [cel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2272172/cel) commented, someone put this as an issue [in github](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/229).
There, they do not answer the question but say that it is a joke related to the original name of the library.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

[Samuel Norman "Sam" Seaborn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sam_Seaborn) is a fictional character portrayed by Rob Lowe on the television serial drama The West Wing.

So, it's a joked initialism.

Comment: there is literally no evidence for this.

Answer (score 8):

From the [FAQ](https://seaborn.pydata.org/faq.html#why-is-seaborn-imported-as-sns) section of the seaborn documentation:

> ### Why is seaborn imported as `sns`?
>
> This is an obscure reference to the
> [namesake](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C3C6q1ZUYAALXX0.jpg) of the library, but you can also think of it as "seaborn name
> space".