# How to map heatmap tick labels to a value and add those values as a legend

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I want to create a heatmap in seaborn, and have a nice way to see the labels.

With `ax.figure.tight_layout()`, I am getting

[image]

which is obviously bad.

Without `ax.figure.tight_layout()`, the labels get cropped.

[image]

The code is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sn

n_classes = 10
confusion = np.random.randint(low=0, high=100, size=(n_classes, n_classes))

label_length = 20

label_ind_by_names = {
    "A"*label_length: 0,
    "B"*label_length: 1,
    "C"*label_length: 2,
    "D"*label_length: 3,
    "E"*label_length: 4,
    "F"*label_length: 5,
    "G"*label_length: 6,
    "H"*label_length: 7,
    "I"*label_length: 8,
    "J"*label_length: 9,
}

# confusion matrix
df_cm = pd.DataFrame(
    confusion,
    index=label_ind_by_names.keys(),
    columns=label_ind_by_names.keys()
)
plt.figure()
sn.set(font_scale=1.2)
ax = sn.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True, annot_kws={"size": 16}, fmt='d')
# ax.figure.tight_layout()


plt.show()
```

I would like to create an extra legend based on `label_ind_by_names`, then post an abbreviation on the heatmap itself, and be able to look up the abbreviation in the legend.

How can this be done in seaborn?

Comment: As an aside, the standard accepted alias for `seaborn` is `sns`, not `sn`. [Seaborn - Why import as sns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41499857/7758804)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I was not familiar with this standard, and copied from somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own [legend handler](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/legend_handler_api.html#matplotlib.legend_handler.HandlerBase.legend_artist), e.g. for integers:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sn

n_classes = 10
confusion = np.random.randint(low=0, high=100, size=(n_classes, n_classes))

label_length = 20

label_ind_by_names = {
    "A"*label_length: 0,
    "B"*label_length: 1,
    "C"*label_length: 2,
    "D"*label_length: 3,
    "E"*label_length: 4,
    "F"*label_length: 5,
    "G"*label_length: 6,
    "H"*label_length: 7,
    "I"*label_length: 8,
    "J"*label_length: 9,
}

# confusion matrix
df_cm = pd.DataFrame(
    confusion,
    index=label_ind_by_names.values(),
    columns=label_ind_by_names.values()
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, right=.65)

sn.set(font_scale=1.2)
sn.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True, annot_kws={"size": 16}, fmt='d', ax=ax)

class IntHandler:
    def legend_artist(self, legend, orig_handle, fontsize, handlebox):
        x0, y0 = handlebox.xdescent, handlebox.ydescent
        text = plt.matplotlib.text.Text(x0, y0, str(orig_handle))
        handlebox.add_artist(text)
        return text

ax.legend(label_ind_by_names.values(),
                 label_ind_by_names.keys(),
                 handler_map={int: IntHandler()},
                 loc='upper left',
                 bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 1))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Explanation of the hard-coded figures: the first two are the left and right extreme positions of the Axes in the figure (0.05 = 5 % for the figure width etc). 1.2 and 1 is the location of the upper left corner of the legend box relative to the Axes (1, 1 is the upper right corner of the Axes, we add 0.2 to 1 to account for the space used by the colorbar). Ideally one would use a constrained layout instead of fiddeling with the parameters but it doesn't (yet) support figure legends and if using an Axes legend, it places it between the Axes and the colorbar.