# What is the difference between these seaborn.boxplot implementations?

Tags: python, seaborn

My current prof entered this code in our tutorial jupyter notebook:

```
f = plt.figure(figsize=(24, 4))  
sb.boxplot(data = hp, orient = "h")
```

but in previous year's tutorial videos, this was the code:

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(24,4))  
sb.boxplot(hp, orient = "h")
```

I have tried to run the 2nd code but it shows up as an error

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

This was the error that I got. I am not sure why it can run on the previous year's tutorial videos but can't on my notebook.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [FutureWarning: Pass the following variables as keyword args: x, y](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64130332/7758804)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is not about `matplotlib`, but `seaborn`. You probably use a 0.11 version.

The `boxplot` function signature for 0.11 series is:

```
sns.boxplot(*, x=None, y=None, hue=None, data=None, ..., **kwargs)
```

So when you use `sns.boxplot(hp, orient='h')`, `hp` is the value for `x` and not `data` parameter. The first version of your code works because you explicitly named the `data` parameter.

Since 0.12 version, the signature is:

```
sns.boxplot(data=None, *, x=None, y=None, ..., **kwargs)
```

The only unnamed argument allowed is `data`, so both of your code will work.

**Solution**: update to Seaborn 0.12 or use `data=hp` as parameter of `boxplot` (and other functions).

Summary:

```
# version 0.11
sns.boxplot(data=hp, orient='h')  # works
sns.boxplot(hp, orient='h')       # failed

# version 0.12
sns.boxplot(data=hp, orient='h')  # works
sns.boxplot(hp, orient='h')       # works
```

Comment: why do you use sns instead of sb (oh i know, i imported seaborn as sb instead of sns)? and also if i update to seaborn 0.12 both ways will work? how do i set the value of x? it will not automatically take it from the hp dataframe i created? thanks!!

Comment: Oh sorry, the habit. In general, we use `import seaborn as sns` because that's what the [official documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/introduction.html) recommends. To specify `x`, use `sns.boxplot(data=hp, x='mycolforx', y='mycolfory')`

Comment: @ClarissaChen [Official FAQ: Why is seaborn imported as sns?](https://seaborn.pydata.org/faq.html#why-is-seaborn-imported-as-sns) and [Why import seaborn as sns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41499857/7758804)